# react : webpackHotDevClient.js:60 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/sockjs-node' failed:

Tags: reactjs, websocket

Im making a react app and i have this error showing up in the javascript console when i run yarn start and i load the page:

```
webpackHotDevClient.js:60 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/sockjs-node' failed:
```

I have tried to look for answers on Stackoverflow but didnt find anything.

I dont know what it is and how to solve it but it seems not preventing the page to load properly...

The error was not showing up until recently, i dont know what i changed.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

for me it worked to disable the "Allow CORS: Access-Control" extension

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).